# Can't fully remove xlwings addin from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins, xlwings

**What I've done so far:**

1. removed xlwings Python module with `pip uninstall xlwings`
2. deleted the `.xlam` file Excel was referenced
3. unchecked the addin from "Excel Addins" inside Excel and it showed a message asking if I wanted to remove it because the original file was not found, so I clicked yes.

When I open Excel the `xlwings.xlam` file is not loaded now.

**Problems:**

1. I still see the xlwings tab in the Ribbon. But when I see in File->Options->Customize Ribbon. I don't see any xlwings reference.

[image]

2. in the Project section of the VBA editor I still see the `xlwings.xlam` addin

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you still have xlwings installed, you can run `xlwings addin remove`.

If not and you installed the add-in by using `xlwings addin install`, it was placed in the `XLSTART` folder. To find out where that is, open the VBA editor via `Alt-F11`, then, in the `Immediate Window`, type: `?Application.StartupPath` and hit Enter. Open the folder of the printed path and delete the add-in (while Excel is closed).

Comment: `Intermediate` should be `Immediate`; the shortcut to open it (if not showing by default) is `Ctrl+G`

Comment: thanks @Felix for the hint. For me, the xlwings Addin, was found at:
`~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Add-Ins.localized/xlwings.xlam` after all uninstall trials ... pip ... xlwings remove ... PS:@at Monterey 12.7.2 /Office 2016

Answer (score 1):

You can trick Excel by saving a new file as an **"xlwings.xlam"** file in the same folder that Excel is looking for.

1. Save a new file as **"xlwings.xlam"** in the said folder. Exit Excel.
2. Start Excel again. Excel should not give any error messages this time since the ".xlam" file does exist.
3. Go to Excel Add-in dialog box, check + Ok. Then uncheck + Ok on this add-in. Exit Excel. This should solve it.
4. After this you can delete the new **"xlwings.xlam"** file.